# Leaderboard not showing correctly

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

As shown in the pictures, the leaderboard percentages on my Stack Overflow page are not showing correctly.

I was until yesterday top 2% of the Quarter, always been keeping up and improving my stats, today I started showing up as top 10% of the Week.

This is my current ranking:

```
2130 (Week Rank) +2550 (change) 1,705 (total reputation) 25 (week reputation)
1734 (Month Rank) +3687 (change) 1,704 (total reputation) 15 (month reputation)
1733 (Quarter Rank) +3066 (change) 1,704 (total reputation) 15 (quarter reputation)
1734 (Year Rank) +10471 (change) 1704 (total reputation) 15 (quarter reputation)
```

I have been member for one year so lately I had been promoter to top 2% of the Quarter and my personal objective was to become top 2% percent of the Year, but looks like everything is resetting now with the new year.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the yearly leaderboards are reset every year, and the quarterly leaderboards are reset every quarter. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), they aren't 'rolling quarters' or something like that. Try to see it from the bright side: you don't need that much reputation now to get on top of the league.

You're now displayed as top 10% of the week as that is the league type you're currently ranked highest in.

Comment: I have to observe, this reputation league is not real time. My week reputation now is 60 points now but league I am still at 25... :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Its for the current year - I don't think any of the counters other than *maybe* week are rolling.

Also I was #2 last year so... yeah, bit of motivation to catch up. Reputation leagues are just for a bit of fun anyway.

Comment: fun but also work... stackoverflow is going to get you a lot of jobs I believe. Still I do feel motivated now.. thanks